# Value not update immediately using useState in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to update a value since `useState` hook but not change immediately. The value has updated when a print the array with a `console.log` but not in the render in a loop. How to update in the render in loop?

```
var itemsList = [];
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

const pushProduct = useCallback(async (id, name, price, quantity) => {
    setItems(items => [...items ,{id, name, price, quantity}])
}, []);

const updateItem = useCallback(async (_id, op=true) => {
    let itemsCopy = [...itemsList];

    itemsList[0].forEach((_item, value, map) => {
        if(_item.id === _id) {
            let itemSelected = {..._item};
            let quantity = Math.floor(_item.quantity)

            op ? quantity += 1 : quantity -= 1;
            
            itemsCopy = itemSelected;
        }
        setItems(items => itemsList[0]);
    }, []);
})

useEffect(() => {
    itemsList.push(items)
}, [items]);
```

when i update from `pushProduct`, useEffect working but not from updateItem

Comment: On line #21 of the posted code (where `}, []);` is)... I assume those brackets where intended to be the dependencies of `useCallback`. It should be on the next line. It should have `itemsList` and `setItems` in it.

Comment: itemsList is not `state`. Then how it will change to get `itemsList[0]`?

Comment: @kan When `pushProduct` is called, `items` changes and trigger the `useEffect`.

Comment: Oh. I see you loop ` itemsList[0]`, do some stuff,  then `setItems(items => itemsList[0])` without change any thing. That mean you setState many time with same value.